# Uncaught ReferenceError: Book1 is not defined

Tags: javascript

I run the code within my web browser to see if it will display  the books I put in my library function. However, the very first thing it shows me is the error"Uncaught ReferenceError: Book1 is not defined" even though I have it defined within my function.I can't figure out what I did wrong.

```
let myLibrary = [];

function Book(name, author, pages, read) {
  this.name = name;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
  this.info = function () {
return name, author, pages, read;
  };
}

function addBookToLibrary(name, author, pages, read) {
  This.newBook = function () {
    const Book1 = new Book1(
      "Rich Dad, Poor Dad",
      "Robert Kiyosaki",
      "235",
      "Read"
    );

const Book2 = new Book2("One Piece", "Eiichiro Oda", "23456", "Not Read");

const Book3 = new Book3("Bone", "Jeff Smith, 2352, Not Read");
  };
}

myLibrary.push(Book1, Book2, Book3);

for (let i in myLibrary) {
  console.log(myLibrary[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: `Book1 = new Book1` - typo

Comment: `new Book1`, `new Book2`, `new Book3` Where are you getting the idea that this is the way you would instantiate a new instance of the `Book` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your constants of `book1`, `book2`, and `book3` inside the function `addBookToLibrary()`, within the function defining `This.newBook`. These constants only exist within the context/environment of the function and cannot be directly referenced outside of it. To call your `push()` function using these books, you should move that line within the function. In addition, you should call the constructor for your `Book` class and not the name of the object: `const Book1 = new Book()`

```
function addBookToLibrary(name, author, pages, read) {
  This.newBook = function () {
    const Book1 = new Book(
      "Rich Dad, Poor Dad",
      "Robert Kiyosaki",
      "235",
      "Read"
    );

const Book2 = new Book("One Piece", "Eiichiro Oda", "23456", "Not Read");

const Book3 = new Book("Bone", "Jeff Smith, 2352, Not Read");
myLibrary.push(Book1, Book2, Book3);
  };
}
```

Your code also never calls `addBookToLibrary()` anyways so there's no way `Book1, Book2, Book3` can even exist in any environment until you run it.